# How to Import and Render Components Dynamically in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to import and render a component in React Dynamically.
there are two component 1st is Dashboard and 2nd is Home so basically, I want to render Dashboard Component in Home Dynamically without importing it previously or maybe import in the render function of the Home Component.

Dashboard.js

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{
  render()
 {
   return( Dashboard Content Goes Here...! )
 }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from ‘react’;

class Home extends Component
{ 
  render()
  { 
    return( // import & render Dashboard component here ) 
  } 
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) or [`react-loadable`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)

Comment: I'm still learning React but I'm not sure it works this way. You could write a method to conditionally render a component but I believe you still have to bring in the component in home. Although using react router and redirecting may also be an option

Answer (score -1):

You can use React.lazy to lazy import a component. What that means is that the component will only be imported when/if that component mounts. This reduces the time your parent component takes to mount. If you are using an appropriately configured webpack, it will create a different bundle for your lazy imported component and will only load that bundle when that component mounts.

```
import React, { Component } from ‘react’;

const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import('...path here'));

class Home extends Component
{ 
  render()
  { 
    return <Dashboard /> 
  } 
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: React.lazy is not available for SSR.